# Need to install Win7 on 8 identical computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, disk-cloning

I am putting together 8 new computers for my dentist. All brand new with exact same hardware. These are generic machines I am assembling with Gigabyte motherboards and not name branded computers. Since his needs are so basic he wanted something small physically and no internal DVD Drives, etc. We also bought 8 new licenses for Windows 7 Professional (64bit) with DVDs.

All legit, nothing illegal going on here. They are using Dental Practice Management software that runs off a shared drive from the server.

I know that I can install the Windows 7 & drivers then run my updates, IE 11, Firefox, Adobe Reader, etc and skip the Windows Key for up to 3 days.

Can I get one computer fully up and running without putting in the Windows 7 keys, make an image using Acronis Truimage (I am not too familiar with sysprep). Then I load the images to all the computers and then put in the Windows Keys? The images will be done using an external USB hard drive and booting off an external USB CD/DVD drive containing teh Acronis CD.

These will be on the network and on the Internet. They are using a simple file server, so there is no AD.

Will this work or do I still need to be concerned about SIDs? I was reading that I need to run sysprep and then clone the disks as it will generalize each computer before I clone. But I was also told that sysprep can only be used 3 times.. not sure if it means 3 times on the base computer or I can make 3 clones?

Comment: "Sysprep can only be used three times" means you sysprep a computer, deploy the image, sysprep that image after it has been deployed, deploy a new image, sysprep that grandchild image depoy for a 3rd time. Now you can nolonger sysyprep that grandchild image to make a great-grandchild.

Answer (score 2):

**You are right on track!**
Create the sys image before the grace period is over, and input key on each separate comp. Not familiar with Acronis Truimage, but should work!

**Sysprep is not limited to 3 comps**, in fact it is designed to be used for your explicit purpose!

SysP Info can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799240(v=ws.10).aspx

The **security identifier** only kicks in when the system is activated or trial expired. So it should be fine even with a standard unlicensed backup iso.

Source: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/54531-63-installing-image-multiple-computers-orig-keys

**Addtional info for you future IT management:** Volume Activation Management Tool 2.0: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff686877.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When installing skip input the key. Install everyting else then make the image and load it to other computers. Then input each key on separate computer.

Comment: While your answer is probably the best solution. It might pay to take the time to expand the concepts out into something more substantial.

Comment: I would definitely recommend you add sources to back up. i.e microsoft technical website info. Thanks for contributing! =)

Answer (score 0):

To do this correctly - creating an answer file, image, and deploying them - you need to look at the OEM Pre-installation Kit - OPK (http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/installation/downloads/Pages/windows_7_opk.aspx) - but I believe you have to be a partner who has signed an OEM agreement to get the kit.  Further, learning the tools effectively for 7 computers may well be very time consuming unless you expect to be doing this regularly for other clients - then it can make sense.

Basically I'm not sure the licensing grants you the right to re-image unless you're an appropriately registered OEM.  Best bet is to contact MS for guidance since the world of licensing is a legal one and no one answering is a lawyer - if they were, they wouldn't be giving legal advice anyway since there are many factors they wouldn't know without knowing a lot more about you/your business.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using images to setup a computer, but I have built and set up computers.  Software is an important role in doing so.  There are what you call volume discs. They come straight froma manufacturer or government organization.  I had a volume disc of XP that was valued at 500 dollars. Such an operating system will find all the drivers and have no limit on how many or what kind of system your running it on.  Then you can assemble as many computers as you want using the same key over and over. Some boot discs have a limit of like three ,but Microsoft knows that things happen to computers. Operating system discs come with a number you can call when its time to use the key. If its just one or two things that appear different on the computer they will accept the key or give you another one for that computer.